# Right to Left for Visual FoxPro

Tags: right-to-left, visual-foxpro, foxpro

Visual FoxPro has right to left feature but it is related to Windows. When Windows has Arabic language it works.

Does anybody know how I can do this without Arabic Windows (like Delphi or VB)?

Comment: To clarify... you have a Arabic-based Windows machine? and VFP is defaulting to a right-to-left context for its alignment of controls and you want to ignore that and have the labels and data left-to-right?

Comment: but most of my users has only english windows and they don't know how to active arabic language

Comment: Is your app written to support BOTH Arabic AND English?